# Spring resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

How to send POST request where must be query parameters in message body?

I tried:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("name", "xx");
map.add("password", "xx");

restTemplate.postForObject("URL", map, Response.class);
```

But it doesn't work. I want to send data into bitstamp api.

EDIT: My spring bean seems:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

EDIT 2: My code seems

```
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);// or any other

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);

HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("key=XX&nonce=XX&signature=XX", headers);
ResponseEntity<AccountBalance> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
"https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, AccountBalance.class);
```

Response is now: Missing key, signature and nonce parameters

But it should be: API key not found

Comment: `query parameters in message body` this is self contradictory.  Query parameters are in the url, the request body is the request body.

Comment: Yes, but i did in SOAPUI and there is button Post Query string into body and then it's works. I can't do have the same result with restTemplate :-(

Comment: Ok, so how send data in request body with restTemplate? Because, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You seem to be missing some core REST concepts.  Maybe start here: http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/ but you may need a more fundamental understanding of REST first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, thank you all :-)

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
body.add("key", "XXX");
body.add("nonce", "XX");
body.add("signature", "XX");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);

ResponseEntity<AccountBalance> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(bitstampBalanceUrl, HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity, AccountBalance.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `restTemplate.exchange`

example:

```
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);// or any other

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);

HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("name=XX&password=XX",headers);
ResponseEntity<Response> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("URL", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Response.class);
```

Comment: I don't uderstand why it doesn't work. Because when I use this method (POST request):
 http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
Then it works perfectly. Is it possible to do it with resttemplate?

Comment: share your code please , it could be the content type ... or something else, share what you are trying to do

Comment: you are still using restTemplate.postForObject, while I advise you yo uer restTemplate.exchange